# Smart Search - Same Content but Different indexes and front-end results

Tags: smartsearch, zoo, joomla3.8.5

I have not a deep experience with the ins and outs of Smart Search.
I am trying to figure out why I am getting different search results after searching with the exact same term in those 2 instances of the same database but the one is on a 3.8.5 Joomla install and the other is on a 3.7.5.
The content is on Zoo and it is identical in both sites. And the only smart search plugin that is enabled is that of the zoo smart search.

I also noticed that for the 3.7.5 site that returns more results, I got a database error of full `#__finder_token` table, during indexing and I had to update MySQL configuration in order to complete the procedure. Overall the indexing is taking longer for this website, like it has more work to do than the other.

In contrast on the 3.8.5 site, indexing was progressing a lot faster and with no the above database problem.

Note that both these 2 websites are on the same server with the exact same setup.

In the statistics of Smart Search I get:

3.7.5 Site:

> The indexed content on this site includes **287,634** terms across 478
>   links with **171** attributes in 9 branches.

3.8.5 Site:

> The indexed content on this site includes **8,883** terms across 478 links
>   with **165** attributes in 9 branches.

I compared all the settings relative to smart search that I could think of, and they seem identical.

What could possibly affect the Smart Search indexing, so I end up with such big differences in the results?

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for this but have a similar issue with a website I migrated from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.x a few months ago.

Comment: Can I suggest you try taking a backup of both sites and putting them on your localhost. Once done, try running the indexer and see if you get the same results mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks @Lodder - I am in a such process in order to perform a combination of tests and comparisons.

Comment: I can't find it but there was a pull request to do with Smart Search not doing something properly.  I wish I had more info but I would look at the release notes for those versions because it was where I saw it.  Here is the pull requests for it, maybe that can help if you reduce the dates down somehow.  https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed+smart+search